# Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I trying to make a wewbservice using maven-springboot. Below are the dependencies I am using in my pom file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>SpringService Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.3.0.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <jackson.library>2.7.5</jackson.library>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
         <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.library}</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

However, I am getting an error **Missing artifact org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.0.RELEASE** for *spring-web*, *spring-core*, and *spring-webmvc*. Kindly, suggest a solution.

Comment: `<version>4${springframework.version}</version>` : you have a typo there, see that **4**?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake while asking this question. I have corrected it in my question.

Comment: I tried your config and it seems file to me. Try to use `-X` flag to find clue in the verbose log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting folder
**/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/springframework**
followed by running `maven install` has worked for me.

Comment: accept your answer as the correct one ;)